# How to use streams to create binary data in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, binary, binarystream

I have a requirement to read a file from drive and pass it on to another API. The target API accepts binary data (like the data read using `fs.readFile()`)

Following is the drive api code

```
var fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/photo.jpg');
drive.files.get({
   fileId: fileId,
   alt: 'media'
})
.on('end', function() {
  console.log('Done');
})
.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error during download', err);
})
.pipe(dest);
```

One way I'm aware of is to follow the above sample and write the file to the file system and read it back from there using `fs.readFile()`. But, I know its a bad practice and just want to keep the file in memory.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Update**

The answer is in the comments of the marked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The streams support binary data as-is.  You don't need to do anything special.  Just pipe one stream to the other, just as you're doing here.  Instead of piping to a file stream like you're doing in this example, you'll pipe to that API's stream.

Comment: I guess the API accepts binary data but not a stream. As I mentioned, the response of fs.readFile(). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pavan If it doesn't accept a stream, then just use `sourceStream.on('data', (chunk) => { api.write(chunk); })`, or whatever is appropriate for whatever this API is.